# Jquery animations not executing at same time - have tried everything

Tags: jquery, css, animation

So I'm making a sidebar.

I had it working perfectly, but I haven't touched the code in about two weeks, and when I came back to it now, it's acting funny.

So let me explain what's happening. The sidebar is narrow on the side, icons only. About 55px wide. When you hover over that, the sidebar expands to 225px wide, showing text to go along with icons. The entire body is moved over 225px so it looks like the sidebar expands pushing the body over.

Like I said, it was working perfectly two weeks ago, and I haven't touched the code.

Now, when I hover over the sidebar it moves the body over first, then it expands the sidebar. It used to do them at the same time and it looked really cool.

Here's my JQuery code:

```
//Hover sidebar, it appears
//Second function called when user leaves hover
$("#sidebar").hover(function() {
    $( "#sidebar" ).stop().animate({width: "225px"},{duration: 200, queue: false}); // Expand sidebar
    $( "#body-row" ).stop().animate({left: "225px"},{duration: 200, queue: false}); // Push body right
}, function() {
    $( "#sidebar" ).stop().animate({width: "55px"},{queue: false, duration: 200}); // Shrink sidebar back
    $( "#body-row" ).stop().animate({left: "55px"},{queue: false, duration: 200}); // move body back left
    $(".hidden-settings").slideUp(); //Slide up settings if they're visible
});
```

What would cause this to not animate at the same time?

I have tried the queue:false, as you see, but that does nothing. Any ideas?

It may be hard to explain, so if you want a live site, I can push something to another directory on my personal site.

**So how can I make two JQuery animations run at the same time, if queue:false isn't doing anything.**

Comment: We don't need a live site. Just a jsFiddle to reproduce the idea would be more than enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop using JS animations where they're not needed. In the `hover` event just add a class like `expanded` to the `body`, or another shared parent element. Then write CSS like:

```
#sidebar {
  width:55px;
  transition:width 200ms;
}
#body-row {
  left:55px;
  transition:left 200ms;
}
.expanded #sidebar {
  width:225px;
}
.expanded #body-row {
  left:55px;
}
```

The browser will now ensure they're synced, and you dropped a lot of unneeded JS. Leave presentational/layout issues to CSS where it should be.

Comment: Wow. I regret posting this. I honestly never even think of CSS for things like this. Thank you so much! So much easier.